# std::vector coruption on reference update

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

I am passing a vector by reference to another class method to input values into the vector. This works fine in the recipient function. The values are confirmed and correct. then about using the vector in the sender function, the vector is corrupted.

### sender/parent function:

```
std::vector<std::string> update_jobs;

client_run_job runner = client_run_job();
runner.check_running_jobs(pids_to_check, update_jobs);

std::cout << "size of vector: " << update_jobs.size() << std::endl;
std::cout << "vector at 0: " << update_jobs.at(0) << std::endl;
std::cout << "vector at 1: " << update_jobs.at(1) << std::endl;
std::cout << "vector at 2: " << update_jobs.at(2) << std::endl;
std::cout << "vector at 3: " << update_jobs.at(3) << std::endl;
std::cout << "vector at 4: " << update_jobs.at(4) << std::endl;
std::cout << "vector at 5: " << update_jobs.at(5) << std::endl;
std::cout << "vector at 6: " << update_jobs.at(6) << std::endl;


for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = update_jobs.begin(); it != update_jobs.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << "iterator: " << *it << std::endl;
}

for(auto const& value: update_jobs)
{
    std::cout << "range: " << value << std::endl;
}
```

### recipient function:

```
std::string client_run_job::check_running_jobs(std::string pids, std::vector<std::string> & codes){
std::vector<std::string> pid_list;
std::cout << "pid list: " << pids << std::endl;

/* split string*/
tokenize(pids,';',pid_list);

std::cout << " count: " << pid_list.size() << std::endl;

for (int i = 0; i < pid_list.size(); i++)
{

    std::string pid = pid_list.at(i);
    std::cout << "############" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pid str: " << pid << std::endl;
    std::cout << "############" << std::endl;

    std::string running_job_id = pid.substr(0, pid.find(':'));
    std::string job_queue_id = pid.substr(pid.find(',') + 1, pid.size() - pid.find(',') );
    pid = pid.substr(pid.find(':') + 1, pid.find(',') - pid.find(':') - 1);
    std::cout << "running_job_id: " << running_job_id << std::endl;
    std::cout << "job_queue_id: " << job_queue_id << std::endl;
    std::cout << "testing pid: " << pid << std::endl;

    std::string file = "./output/output_" + pid + ".exit";
    std::string temp = running_job_id + ":" + pid+"," + job_queue_id;
    std::cout << "to write: " << temp << std::endl;

    if ( ! is_empty_file( file ) )
    {

        if ( success_exit(file) )
        {
            /* success */
            codes.push_back( temp + ";success");
        }
        else
        {
            /* error */
            codes.push_back( temp + ";error");
        }
    }
    else
    {

        int pid_number = std::stoi(pid);

        if ( pid_number < 0)
        {
            codes.push_back( temp + ";error");
        }
        else if( ! _pid_exist(pid_number) )
        {
            /* Canceled */
            codes.push_back( temp + ";canceled");
        }
    }


    std::cout << "================" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "last entry: " << codes.back() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "================" << std::endl;
}}
```

### Output:

```
pid list: 2:6049,1;3:6157,1;4:6242,1;5:6855,1;8:7218,1;9:4952,2;10:5098,3
count: 7
############
pid str: 2:6049,1
############
running_job_id: 2
job_queue_id: 1
testing pid: 6049
to write: 2:6049,1
================
last entry: 2:6049,1;canceled
================
############
pid str: 3:6157,1
############
running_job_id: 3
job_queue_id: 1
testing pid: 6157
to write: 3:6157,1
================
last entry: 3:6157,1;canceled
================
############
pid str: 4:6242,1
############
running_job_id: 4
job_queue_id: 1
testing pid: 6242
to write: 4:6242,1
================
last entry: 4:6242,1;canceled
================
############
pid str: 5:6855,1
############
running_job_id: 5
job_queue_id: 1
testing pid: 6855
to write: 5:6855,1
================
last entry: 5:6855,1;canceled
================
############
pid str: 8:7218,1
############
running_job_id: 8
job_queue_id: 1
testing pid: 7218
to write: 8:7218,1
================
last entry: 8:7218,1;canceled
================
############
pid str: 9:4952,2
############
running_job_id: 9
job_queue_id: 2
testing pid: 4952
to write: 9:4952,2
================
last entry: 9:4952,2;canceled
================
############
pid str: 10:5098,3
############
running_job_id: 10
job_queue_id: 3
testing pid: 5098
to write: 10:5098,3
================
last entry: 10:5098,3;canceled
================
size of vector: 7
vector at 0: ▒▒▒U;canceled
vector at 1: 3:6157,1;canceled
vector at 2: 4:6242,1;canceled
vector at 3: 5:6855,1;canceled
vector at 4: 8:7218,1;canceled
vector at 5: 9:4952,2;canceled
vector at 6: 10:5098,3;canceled
iterator: ▒▒▒U;canceled
iterator: 3:6157,1;canceled
iterator: 4:6242,1;canceled
iterator: 5:6855,1;canceled
iterator: 8:7218,1;canceled
iterator: 9:4952,2;canceled
iterator: 10:5098,3;canceled
range: ▒▒▒U;canceled
range: 3:6157,1;canceled
range: 4:6242,1;canceled
range: 5:6855,1;canceled
range: 8:7218,1;canceled
range: 9:4952,2;canceled
range: 10:5098,3;canceled
```

## I have tired Deque, Deque did not solve the problem.

I believe this may be an Iterator validity issue, not sure how to fix to it while using a vector or deque, which I receive the same error with deque.

Comment: Function signatures would be helpful here.

Comment: O wow I am stupid

Comment: Is there any way you could cut this down to a [minimal, compile-able example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  Ideally, someone could just copy it into an online compiler and run your code.

Comment: With due respect - Please consider deleting the question and the answer, since I doubt they will be helpful to other readers.

Comment: You're not stupid. You made a mistake. I do that crap all the time, and I've got nearly 30 years experience. This gets less frequent as you get more experience, but what *really* changes is your ability to spot it after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the problem was incorrect function signature:

```
std::string check_running_jobs(std::string pids, std::vector<std::string> & codes);
bool _pid_exist(int pid);
bool is_empty_file(std::string file);
bool success_exit(std::string file);
void tokenize(std::string const &str, const char delim, std::vector<std::string> &out);
```

I needed to update the return for "check_running_jobs"

```
std::string check_running_jobs(std::string pids, std::vector<std::string> & codes);
```

to

```
void check_running_jobs(std::string pids, std::vector<std::string> & codes);
```

The credit goes to @3Dave who pointed me in the right direction.

To go into what caused this error in hopes to help others in the same situation as me no matter how unlikely.

Using g++ 7.4.0 with Codeblocks 16.01 When you have massive projects or projects inside of projects the compiler will attempt to compile with clear errors and cause undefined behavior.. ( as this is what happened to me )

The compiler should have picked up this function signature error, I found other instances where I should not have been allowed to compile the code, that created undefined behavior issues.

Comment: The function should have never compiled but codeblocks is not good.

Comment: using g++ 7.4.0 with codeblocks 16.01 When you have massive projects or projects inside of projects the compiler will attempt to compile with clear errors and cause undefined behavior.. ( as this is what happened to me )

Answer (score 1):

I'll first say that it's unclear why changing the return type should have helped you at all. Like you said in the comment on your own answer - this sounds like a compiler issue.

So my first piece of advice is:

1. Use a reputable compiler (<- not actually sure what you were using)
2. Turn on warning flags. For gcc or clang, try `-Wall -Wextra` (actually there are more useful warning to turn on); for MSVC, try `/W4`.
3. Take a careful look at where the warnings warn you about, and try to address the issue they raise. If you don't understand what the warning means - search for it on the web (or here on SO).

Now, you would probably have avoided the whole thing if you had designed your function different. Let's have a look at the signature again:

```
std::string check_running_jobs(std::string pids, std::vector<std::string> & codes);
```

This doesn't make sense in multiple ways. `check_running_jobs()` - check what? And do what after you've checked? It's not like you said `check_running_jobs_are_healthy()` or `_are_ready()` etc. Or if you throw an exception on failure. you would have called the function `ensure_running_jobs_are_healthy( ... )` and added `noexcept(false)` to clarify you might throw.

With a decent name, the return type would have been obvious: A boolean ("they are healthy" or "they aren't healthy); or perhaps some status type (`job_status_t`). You would then have noticed that the return type you chosed doesn't match the name. The way things stand, it doesn't match the name anyway.

Fnally, there's `codes`. What's that about? A function which checks things doesn't fill vectors of things. Also, what do "codes" have to do with checking jobs? If you want to return a "status code" for each job, then you would have this signature:

```
std::vector<status_code_t> get_running_jobs_status(std::string running_job_pids)
```

and if the status code is a string, no problem, it's still the right signature, you just add:

```
using status_code_t = std::string;
```

earlier in your program.

This advice is a particular case of the C++ core guideline F.22: [prefer return values to output parameters](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#f20-for-out-output-values-prefer-return-values-to-output-parameters).

There are some other issues (such as separating the parsing of the pid-list string into a container of pid's, and how each pid shouldn't be a string but a number, etc.) but the last one I'll mention here is that you should never have output stream commands like in your "sender/parent" function - because those assume that the vector is of a certain length, while it really doesn't have to be. That's undefined behavior and will either print junk or possibly cause a segmentation violation.

There are a few issues with your code, which, had you addressed them all, you probably would not have had this problem.

With due respect - Please consider deleting the question and the answer, since I doubt they will be helpful to other readers. Also, try to avoid using "return parameters", like non-const references, especially in void-returning functions. It's doubly confusing since your fu

Comment: Does CodeBlocks really use its own compiler? That's silly. Given the amount of industry effort put into clang, I'm surprised anyone uses anything else. (I'll give MS a break on this one, for the moment.)

Comment: @3Dave: Actually, I don't know. Probably not. Edited.

Comment: I don't know either! It would be weird, but not unheard-of. :) Not paying attention to warnings is a likely factor here.

Comment: using g++ 7.4.0 with codeblocks 16.01 When you have massive projects or projects inside of projects the compiler will attempt to compile with clear errors and cause undefined behavior.. ( as this is what happened to me )